# .htaccess restrict ip to url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im trying to restrict access to the /admin path (Not actual directory) on my web server to a set of IP address'. Here's what i have now, however it doesnt seem to set function as expected.

This is for Craft CMS, below is my .htaccess file sitting in /public_html.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
        RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

        # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]


        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
        RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10.6.
        RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192.168.
        RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^172.17.
        RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What exactly isnt working?

Comment: Just does nothing regarding the /admin restriction

Comment: Your /admin rule is in an unreachable possion where engine cant reach to excute it. Try reordering your rules put your /admin rules and conds at top

Comment: ty, write as answer if you want